# How to test Interrupt Latency?

Tags: c++, c, windows, embedded, windows-ce

Windows Embedded Compact 7.

Is there a way to test interrupt latency time from user space?

Are there any tools provided as part of platform builder?

I also saw a program called Intrtime.exe - but no examples on how to use it.

How does one test the interrupt latency time?

Reference for Intrtime.exe but how do I implement it?
 http://www.ece.ufrgs.br/~cpereira/temporeal_pos/www/WindowsCE2RT.htm

**EDIT**
Also found:

> ILTiming.exe Real-Time Measurement Tool (Compact 2013)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee483144.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This really is a test that requires hardware, and there are a couple "latencies" you might measure.  Once is the time from the interrupt signal to when the driver ISR reacts and the second is from when the interrupt occurs to when an IST reacts.

[I did this back in the CE 3.0/CE 4.0 days](http://www.eurotech-inc.com/info/white-papers/Whitepaper_Realtime.pdf) by attaching a signal generator to an interruptable input an then having an ISR pulse a second input and an IST pulse a third input when they received the interrupt.  I hooked a scope up to the input and outputs and used it to measure time between the input signal and output signals to get not just latency, but also jitter.  You could easily add a 4th line for CE 7 so you could check an IST in user space and an IST in kernel space.  I'd definitely be interested to see the results.

I don't think you can effectively measure this with software running on the platform, as you get into the problem of the code trying to do the measurement affecting the results.  You're also talking time way, way below the system tick resolution so the scheduler is going to be problematic as well.  CeLog might be able to get you an idea on these times, but getting it set up and running is probably more work than just hooking up a scope.

Comment: Think I also saw your report on msdn. not sure I can get a scope in time.... Just curious, is the ISR code user defined or where can I see/modify it?

Comment: The ISR is either in the BSP, or if the platform has installable ISRs (IISR support), then you could have it in your code.  If it's in the BSP, then you'd need the source code for it.

Answer (score 1):

What is usually meant by interrupt latency is the time between an interrupt source asserting the interrupt line and a thread (sometimes in user-space) being scheduled and then executing as a result.

Unless your CPU has some accurate way of time-stamping interrupt events as they arrive at the CPU (rather than when an ISR runs), the only truly accurate measurement is one done externally - by measuring the time between a the interrupt line being asserted and some observable signal that the thread responding to the interrupt can control.   A DSO or logic analyser is usually used for this purpose.

Software techniques usually rely on storing an accurate time-stamp at the earliest opportunity in an ISR.  If you're certain the time between interrupt line becoming asserted and the ISR running is negligible, this might be valid.  If, on the other hand, disabling of interrupts is being used to control concurrency, or interrupts are nested, you probably want to be measuring this as well.

Comment: assuming the time from the interrupt line to the ISR is negligible and I have a high resolution timer: how do I create the interrupt, in what/where ISR code do I put the start time stamp and end time stamp before the ISThread? Thank you.